# Updating Model from Database EF6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, sql-server-2014-express

Following from my [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44469411/database-schema-for-managing-addresses) in which I used `SQL` server and Entity framework. As in initial stage I set address `id` as not null in database and similarly I also created a parameter user `id` in address field which is also not nullable. Now I am stuck as one of these needs to created first. So I set `userid` field as allow null in db and tried updating model from database but it throws error

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error       Running transformation: Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'User' in relationship 'FK_Addresses_Areas1'. Because all the properties in the Dependent Role are nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role must be '0..1'.   Lightmap    C:\Users\Rohit\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Lightmap\Lightmap\Models\Lightmap.edmx 467

Now I can't resolve this. Can anybody help?

[database schema for managing addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44469411/database-schema-for-managing-addresses)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're working with an EDMX, the problem you're having is because the database isn't matching what's setup in the EDMX for `userid` in the address table.

Your immediate problem can be fixed by populating the null `userid` fields then reverting `userid` back to not null. The database will be happy and you'll be able to update the model from the database again.

*There's more...*

IF you are happy with address being nullable, then you can fix the error by:

1. Going into the EDMX and selecting the association link
2. In the properties, change the `End1 Multiplicity` to `0..1 (Zero or one of ___)`

Here's a random mock up of an edmx where you can find those properties
[image]